# How to make a redirect (301) in Node.js / Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express

I have a static site, a simple single page layout that I deploy in Dokku. I need to make a redirect (301) from www to non www and from `*.website1.com` to `website2.com`, but I don't know how. I was trying to use express-force-domain in npm but it makes my URL's crazy and having some redirect loops, I was trying other methods that I find on the web but none succeeds.

my server.js is:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 80))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

That is the version that works, but without redirects.

Comment: The response object has a method `redirect(url)`. I would start there.

Comment: non-www to www redirects should preferably be done with a redirect in the server admin panel etc. and not in Node? How you would do that with dokku is beyond me, but here's [something](http://www.neilmiddleton.com/doing-dns-right-with-heroku/) for Heroku !

Comment: my server dont have an admin panel, it is a cloud server on digital ocean

Answer (score 80):

```
res.redirect(301, 'http://yourotherdomain.com' + req.path)
```

See [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect).

Answer (score 29):

To anyone arriving here from Google, while @frederic's answer is still what is recommended by the express docs, the `response.send(status, body)` style has been deprecated and will generate a warning (I am on express 4.13.4 at time of writing), and more importantly I found that it no longer produced the desired result when redirecting.

As @Markasoftware mentioned, to achieve an automatically followed 301, you need to set the location header to the url you want. The request body can be empty:

```
   response.set('location', 'https://my.redirect.location');
   response.status(301).send()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, to set an HTTP 301 code, you would set the response code to be `301` and then set the `Location` header to whatever url you want it to redirect to. I don't think this is the preferred way to do www to non-www urls though

Comment: yes, i was try this but doesn't work, my big problem is to redirect domain1 to domain2, the www to non www comes after. So another problem comes up, my dokku dont recognize another sites, it always open the same site, i dont know why