# How do I properly setup a 301 redirect with my current nodejs express setup?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

I'm a little bit confused on how I setup the redirect. My attempts keep leading to "too many redirects".

I want my domain.herokuapp.com to redirect to www.domain.com.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var appdata = require('../data.json');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', {
   title: 'Home',
   page: 'home'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24554299/5156280) post says, you can use `res.redirect()` to make a 301 redirection:

```
res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com');
```

You can look at express documentation regarding redirection at: [Express API Reference](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect)

So in your case:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(301, 'www.domain.com');
});
```

Comment: So I tried this and what it gives me is this result:        "http://domain.herokuapp.com/www.domain.com"

Comment: I guess you need to precise `http://` in your url. Try `res.redirect(301, 'http://www.domain.com');`