# Redirect not working in node.js using express

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var PORT = process.env.PORT||3000;
var _ = require('underscore');
var db = require('./db.js');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.post('/users/login',function(req,res){
console.log("Inside post method. Trying to redirect");
        return res.redirect(301,'/home.html');
  });


db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log('Express listening on port ' + PORT + '!');
    });
});
```

Redirect should redirect to a new page home.html after a post request but its not working. Not sure what i am doing wrong here. Before redirecting i was reading user detail from db which I have deleted in this code.
index.html

```
<form ng-app="loginForm" name="userForm" ng-controller="loginController" novalidate>
   <div >
       <label name="email">Email</label>
       <input type="email" style="text-align:center;" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
       <span style="color:red" ng-show="userForm.email.$dirty && userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.email.$touched"> Invalid Email address </span> <p style="color:red"> {{email}} </p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label name="password">Password</label>
   <input type="password" style="text-align:center;"name="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
   <span style="color:red" ng-show="userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$invalid && userForm.password.$touched"> Invalid password</span> <p style="color:red"> {{password}} </p>
   <p style="color:red">{{mess}}</p>
   <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" />
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Controller:

Service using factory:

```
angular.module('httpService',[]).
factory('TCPService',['$http',function($http){
return {
  login : function(user) {
    return $http.post('/users/login',user);
  },
  create : function(user) {
  return  $http.post('/users', user);
  }
}
}]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('logControllers',[])
.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http','TCPService','$window',
function($scope,$http,TCPService,$window){
$scope.login = function(){

  function validate(){
     if($scope.user==null ){
          $scope.mess = "Email id and password are required!";
     }else if(!$scope.user.password || !$scope.user.email){
         if(!$scope.user.password)
         $scope.password = "Password is required";
         if(!$scope.user.email)
         $scope.email = "Email is required";
         return false;
     }

     return true;
   }

   if(validate()){
     TCPService.login($scope.user).then(function(res){
       $scope.mess = "Logged in";
     }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error.data);
     });
   }
}
}]);
```

[Network trace1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2yi0.jpg)
[Network trace2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjJgA.jpg)

Comment: It should be like res.redirect('/home.html'); you need to create anothe app.get method and serve html page from there.

Comment: Do you have a route defined for `/home.html`?  And, is the `/users/login` request coming from a browser form post or from a Javascript Ajax request?  Ajax calls do not change the page the browser is showing at all by themselves.

Comment: @Sagar - The `return` in `return res.redirect(...)` makes no difference at all in that particular route.

Comment: /users/login coming from here. Its a factory that is being used by the controller.

angular.module('httpService',[]).
factory('TCPService',['$http',function($http){
return {
  login : function(user) {
    return $http.post('/users/login',user);
  },
  create : function(user) {
  return  $http.post('/users', user);
  }
}
}]);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect (301) in Node.js / Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151929/how-to-make-a-redirect-301-in-node-js-express)

Comment: There is no Ajax. why I need to create app.get? I searched online. Everyone is redirecting from post it self. Is it not possible from there?

Comment: If you want a person to see your comment and get notified about it, you need to put their name in front of the comment such as @xxxx (see example above).  Otherwise they may not see your comment.  node.js servers no files at all by default.  So, if you don't have a route handler for a given URL, node.js won't do anything for that URL.  So, if you're redirecting to `/home.html`, then you have to have a route for that.  That's how node.js works unless you set up routing to handle a number of static assets using `express.static()`.

Comment: @jfriend00  I have used express.static() for /public directory and home.html is present in that directory. public directory is present in the project directory.

Comment: Well, there isn't enough detail here to know why `express.static()` isn't doing what you want for that file.  To start with, you need to show the network trace in the browser to see exactly what is happening in the browser.  Is it getting the redirect and trying to follow it and getting a 404?  Or what error is happening in the browser?  Or is it not getting the redirect?

Comment: @jfriend00 If I remove html from home.html. It will show 404. So, I am using it. Instead in the network i see entire html in response.body. but it just not redirecting. I have attached screenshot of the trace in the description at the end.

Comment: How is the request being made in the first place?

Comment: See the GET to `/users/login` that immediately follows the POST.  That's a problem.   You are probably getting the redirect, but then the browser is reloading the form page, overriding the redirect.  I would guess the problem is that you are calling `form.submit()` from Javascript, but not blocking the default form post behavior somehow.  Anyway, there should not be a `GET /users/login` right after the `POST /users/login`.  That's where the problem is.  I'd have to see the actual web page and Javascript to know exactly what is causing and what to suggest to fix.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated all the codes here. I am completely new in node and angular both.

Comment: Hey dude, `$http.post('/users/login',user);` looks exactly like an Ajax call to me.  Ajax calls DON'T redirect the browser in any way.  They just return the response (whatever it is) to your Javscript.  If you want the page to change, you have to look at the response in your Javascript and set `window.location` to the new location to manually redirect with your Javascript.  Or use an actual browser form post (not from Javascript) that will follow the redirect.

Comment: And, it also looks like you're not blocking the default form post too which is also a problem if you're posting from Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 window.location was working once in javascript. You can be right. Is there anyway I can avoid it. I am learning. I also want to maintain sessions. Is there anyway I can make it simple. Any tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know angular (and did not know you were using angular when I started helping you with this question).  You need to look for a good angular example of sending a form post with angular and redirecting the response.  That example should cover both preventing default browser form submission and handling redirect upon response.  I know how to do it in plain browser Javascript, just not using angular.

Comment: Can you check the logs in server whether the code in Node JS is being reached ?
Can you see this message in logs ?

"Inside post method. Trying to redirect"

Comment: @rach8garg - The browser network trace screen shots show the POST being sent and the 302 response coming back.  The problem is not on the server.  It's in the angular code in the client.

Comment: So what happens when you clear the cache and load the page again ?
@TringTring