# Is it possible to add a response header for a redirect? (Express)

Tags: node.js, express, http

With Express in NodeJS, I’m trying to redirect to another url, and then add a header to the response of that redirect. Is this possible? For example, a request is redirected to https://example.com and that response has a header that would not normally be on a response from https://example.com.

Comment: does this answer your question? [How to make a redirect (301) in Node.js / Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151929/how-to-make-a-redirect-301-in-node-js-express)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mention where you want the redirection to occur!

If it's in a separate API request, for instance, you can create a middleware, you will use it with the redirected request

```
function Redirectmiddleware (req, res, next) => {

            res.header('HeaderName', value)

    next()
}
```

Then you can use the middleware with the API request that will handle the redirection

```
app.post('/api/redirect', Redirectmiddleware , YourHandlerHere)
 // here you can use the same handler you are using for the https://example.com
//only this redirect request will have the header you passed
```

Comment: Thanks, although would this be possible for a redirect that is not to the api?

Comment: Yes, you can redirect to a certain URL, by doing something like this 

res.redirect('http: //example .com') or a path res.redirect('/user')